# Math.floor why is this rounding down incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, math

I have been using this for sometime now before I noticed that is not reliable

```
Math.floor(16.65*100) / 100 = 16.64
```

Why does this happen? Any reliable alternative for rounding down safely in JS?

Comment: `Math.floor(16.65*100) * 100 ` is return 166400. Any typo?

Comment: Can you reread your question? The answer should be 166500. Did you accidentally multiply instead of divide in your example above?

Comment: I've said this before, and I'll say it again - in floating point math rounding should only be done as the _final_ step, and only for _presentation_ of the value.   This is why `Number.prototype.toFixed` returns a _string_.

Comment: Cannot add this as the answer as its marked as duplicate, but to answer the second part of the question about reliable alternatives: I have had good experience with https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js library for floating point operations. They have a light version of that library as well: https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js-light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `16.65 * 100` is calculated to `1664.9999999999998`

Comment: Great answer. Here's a jsFiddle illustrating it: https://jsfiddle.net/dajskz4m/2/